# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Error when running java program on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, raspberry-pi

I am using java to read from a webpage using this code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {

    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.example.com/");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
}
}
```

When I run the code with eclipse on my windows pc it works fine, but when I try to run it on my raspberry pi, I get this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:     sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid     certification path to requested target
```

I think it means java doesn’t trust the website, but I can’t find a solution anywhere.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating java as described here fixed the problem

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=200232

Comment: This is a link-only answer - if the link dies, the answer contains no useful information. See [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/284827) or [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/284827) for more information.